# How to import csv and access table data?

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to import a csv file (`test.csv`) using pandas `read_table()` and then assign each of the columns to a new variable.

`test.csv` contains the following:

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
1,2,3
1,2,3
```

I am able to import the data as a table and print it to the console. However, I am unable to assign columns to variables.

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_table('test.csv')
print(data)
```

What is the syntax to assign a column of table data to a variable? I tried
`x = data.a` and `x = data['a']`. Neither of these seem to work. What is the appropriate way to import a csv as a table?

Comment: let me know if my answer helps

Comment: what did you get with `print(x)` ?

Comment: why to assign column to variable if you can use `data` with pandas's functions to work much easier.

Comment: `... Neither of these seem to work.` - What happens? `x = data['a']` should assign that Series (column) to the name `x`. Why isn't isn't this sufficient for your purpose?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: The OP states that it does not work because `read_table` was used. I have provided an answer that addresses the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `read_csv` Pandas method:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
print(data)
#   a  b  c
#0  1  2  3
#1  1  2  3
#2  1  2  3
```

Then:

```
x = data.a # OR x = data['a']
```

Or even better (to get numpy arrays as variables):

```
x = data.a.values # OR x = data['a'].values
print(x)
#[1 1 1]
```